# AWS EC2 /usr/bin/docker-compose: cannot execute binary file

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, aws-ssm

I created an EC2 instance and installed docker on it, now I need to install `docker-compose` using SSM `send-command` and to do that I'm running the following command:

```
aws ssm send-command --instance-ids "${INSTACES_ID}" \
    --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" \
    --parameters "commands=[
            sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.22.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)"  -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose,
            sudo mv /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose,
            sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose,
            docker-compose --version
        ]"
```

The commands are executed correctly but the command `docker-compose --version` raises the following exception

```
"StandardErrorContent": "... /usr/bin/docker-compose: cannot execute binary file\nfailed to run commands: exit status 126"
```

I entered in EC2 via ssh the problem is the same, I also tried to give all permissions to bin file

```
$ ls -la /usr/bin | grep docker-compose
-rwxrwxrwx  1 ec2-user ec2-user  6204149 27 set 15.10 docker-compose
$ docker-compose --version
-bash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: What kind of file is it?  (Run those same commands locally and run `file docker-compose`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze `/usr/bin/docker-compose: Mach-O 64-bit executable`

Comment: You've come up with a MacOS binary.  (Probably because in your `aws ssm` command, `uname -s` is getting run by the shell on your MacOS host before anything is sent across to AWS; try putting `echo` at the front of the command to see how the shell expands it.)  For Docker you need a Linux binary, even on a MacOS host.

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you, now it work hard coding string!